# Bring back the replaced database?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Story:

I tried to restore my backup database using a different name (The backup database name is "db1" and db1 is still existing in sql server. In restore, I renamed the "To Database" field into "db2"). Then after restoring, it gave an error saying "db1.log cannot be overwritten because it is still in use (or something like that)" error. Then I realized, I forgot to rename the physical file in "File" page and that caused my problem... Now db1 has a status of "Restoring..." and I don't know what to do anymore...

Is it possible to restore db1?

PS: db1.bak is outdated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the box in the backup that is for overwriting the existing database?

Comment: Nope, I didn't. (I think?)

That checkbox is found in "Options" page, right? If yes, nope, I did not check it. It is unchecked by default

Comment: You should be able to issue the command: RESTORE DATABASE db1 WITH RECOVERY. This will put it back in "normal" state.